# Select where first character is number

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to organize my content by the first character. By now, I did something like this:

**PHP:**

```
$first_char = $_GET['search'];
$sql = "SELECT id
        FROM table
        WHERE SUBSTR(title,1,1) = '".$first_char."'"
....
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="?search=a">[A]</a>
<a href="?search=b">[B]</a>
...
<a href="?search=z">[Z]</a>
<a href="?search=nr">[#]</a>
```

The thing is that when [A] is clicked, it shows titles starting with "A".
What I want to do is when [#] is clicked, it should show all the posts starting with a number. So, when **$_GET = 'nr'** it shows all the titles starting with a number... I tried to do this with array(), but I failed.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT id
        FROM table
        WHERE SUBSTR(title,1,1) in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)"
```

Comment: This answer didn't work for me until I put single quotes around each digit in the 'in' array.  Without the quotes it seems they were being interpreted as fields and not values.

Comment: The same for me, needed numbers as strings in quotes.

Answer (score 3):

The easy way is using [regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
where yourField REGEXP '^[[:digit:]].*$'
```

EDIT explain the RegExp

```
 ^               Start string
 [[:digit:]]     digit one time
 .               everything
  *              zero or more times
 $               End Of String
```

Read comments to view that

```
  .*$
```

is not necessary :)

Comment: Why not just `^[[:digit:]]`? And surely regex is overkill.

Comment: Certainly Tomalak, I try without .* and it's not necessary. I leave the code and comments to make an approach to RegExp.

Comment: The trailing `.*` is simply completely redundant when you don't include an end anchor (`$`). If you want to teach introductory regex, teach it right! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if ($_GET['search'] == 'nr') {
    $where = "REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]'";
} else {
    $where = "= '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']) . "'";
}

$sql = "SELECT .... FROM table WHERE $where";
```